# Correct Format for Transformation Rastio - from_origin

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio, affine-transformation

I am attempting to translate an HDF image to a GeoTIFF file and I encountered an issue when working with the transform module from rasterio. The issue comes when defining the transformation using 'from_origin', when I follow the format provided in the documentation the image is shifted north of where it should be and the origin ends up being 101 latitude, when it should be ~57. See the image below.

[image]

I also tried using affine but this flips the image vertically. I have included the current code here. I am also wondering if there could be an issue with the projection or way I am exporting the data.

```
            crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}  # WGS84 coordinate system
            transform = from_origin(regular_longitude[0], regular_latitude[-1], 
                                    regular_longitude[1] - regular_longitude[0], 
                                    regular_latitude[0] - regular_latitude[1])
            # transform = rasterio.Affine(regular_longitude[1] - regular_longitude[0], 0, 
            #                             regular_longitude[0], 0, 
            #                             regular_latitude[0] - regular_latitude[1], regular_latitude[-1])

            # Create a GeoTIFF file using rasterio
            raster_outname = tmpdir + out_file + '_band_' + str(i) + '.tif'

            with rasterio.open(
                    raster_outname,
                    'w',
                    driver='GTiff',
                    height=interpolated_values.shape[0],
                    width=interpolated_values.shape[1],
                    count=1,
                    dtype=interpolated_values.dtype,
                    crs=crs,
                    transform=transform,
            ) as tif_dataset:
                tif_dataset.write(interpolated_values, 1)
```

Regular longitude and latitude are defined as a np.linspace between the minimum and maximum values of the image that I am translating,

```
regular_latitude = np.linspace(min(lats_FKM.ravel()), max(lats_FKM.ravel()), 3000, dtype=np.single)
regular_longitude = np.linspace(min(lons_FKM.ravel()), max(lons_FKM.ravel()), 3000, dtype=np.single)
```

Comment: @user2856 I have added the definition of the values - this was done to create a regular grid for interpolation.

Comment: Your `from_origin` is incorrect, you're passing in a negative `ysize`, pass in a positive `ysize`.  Rasterio is possibly a little inconsistent here as usually you define the y size component of an affine matrix as negative because origin is top-left so map Y coordinates decrease as pixel row numbers increase, however rasterio "helpfully" [negates the `ysize` for you](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/transform.py#L177).  The `Affine` is right, I've checked against the transform of a correctly georeferenced image.

Comment: If your image is upside down with a correct affine transform, then your numpy array is probably flipped.